# CreatedById is null after insert - Test Class

Tags: apex, unit-test

My understanding of CreatedById was that it gets populated on insert, and that it is not nillable. However, I am trying to test some functionality that depends on the field being populated and it is still null, **even if I insert it, use system.runAs, and set seeAllData=true**.

Is this field simply not accessible in a test method? The gist:

```
@isTest(seeAllData=true)
static void testCreatedBy()
{
    User currentOwner = new User();
    insert currentOwner;

    Case transferRequest = new Case();

    Test.startTest();
        system.runAs(currentOwner)
        {
            insert transferRequest;
        }
    Test.stopTest();

    system.assertNotEquals(null, transferRequest.CreatedById, 'The Created By field should not be null after insert'); // fails
}
```

Comment: Can you post your test code?

Comment: Are you running system.runas before you insert the record?

Comment: Who is currentOwner???  I always try to stay away from using (seeAllData=true).  I try to always create my own test data.  So i would create a user, insert them.  Then create the case, run as that newly created user, and insert.  I personally try to always create my own test data

Comment: It is a user I created in the test. The only reason seeAllData is on is to try to gain visibility to CreatedBy.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Any updates on a record made upon an insert by an Apex trigger, workflow or something like that, will NOT reflect in the object representation you have in memory of that record.
So, as `CreatedById` is filled upon insertion, you have to query the object again.

```
transferRequest = [select Id, CreatedById /*, ANYOTHERFIELDS*/ from Case where Id =: transferRequest.Id limit 1];
```

Then `CreatedById` won't be null;

Comment: Duh. Ah that's so obvious too.