# How can I get the product ID in a test case from a OpportunityLineItem?

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test

I have followed the instructions here [How to Create Opportunity Line Items in Test Classes](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/72883/how-to-create-opportunity-line-items-in-test-classes)

When I try to run the test the Product2ID on the Line Item is null.
How can I fix this to get the correct product ID?

```
Id pricebookId = Test.getStandardPricebookId();

Account account = new Account();
account.Name = 'Test Account';
account.Relationship_Type__c = 'Customer';
account.Facility_Type__c = 'Clinic';
insert account;

//Create product
Product2 prod = new Product2(
Name = 'Test Product',
ProductCode = 'TEST',
isActive = true
);
insert prod;

//Create pricebook entry
PricebookEntry pbEntry = new PricebookEntry(
Pricebook2Id = pricebookId,
Product2Id = prod.Id,
UnitPrice = 100.00,
IsActive = true
);
insert pbEntry;

Opportunity opp = new Opportunity(
AccountId = account.id,
Name = 'Test Opportunity',
Type = 'New Business',
CloseDate = system.today(),
StageName = 'Case Open'
);
insert opp;

//create the opportunity line item.
OpportunityLineItem oli = new OpportunityLineItem(
OpportunityId = opp.Id,
Quantity = 1,
PricebookEntryId = pbEntry.Id
);
insert oli;
System.debug('OLI P2ID ' + oli.Product2Id);
```

Comment: You are debugging "oli.Product2Id", but you have not set Product2Id field with some value on Opportunity Line Item Object. ---- oli.Product2Id = pbEntry.Product2Id; insert oli.

Comment: @heisenberg product2Id is not writable so the only way you can associate product2 to a pricebook is through the pricebook entry as the OP has done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@fredb your code is perfectly fine,

you cannot associate product2Id on opportunityLineItem, you will see an error that says

> Field not writable : Product2

Look at these posts :

[Why is my reference field returning null my test code?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1885/why-is-my-reference-field-returning-null-my-test-code)

[CreatedById is null after insert - Test Class](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/14690/createdbyid-is-null-after-insert-test-class)

Short answer: Any updates on a record made upon an insert by an Apex trigger, workflow or something like that, will NOT reflect in the object representation you have in memory of that record. So, as CreatedById is filled upon insertion, you have to query the object again.
**(credits to: @André Santos de Medeiros)**

Before your debug statement query for the product2Id and your debug statement will not return null.

```
OpportunityLineItem oli1 = [select id,product2Id,opportunityId,quantity from OpportunityLineItem where id=: oli.id];
System.debug('OLI P2ID ' + oli.Product2Id);
```